# Solving limits with powers of x

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$L=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {3^x + 4^x - 2^{x+1} }{x} $$

Can anyone explain how to solve this and similar questions?

Comment: Start by rewriting $a^x = e^{x\ln a}$. If you are allowed to use Taylor series, an "easy and systematic" way is then to expand each term in the denominator to order 1 (i.e., $e^{x\ln a} = 1+x\ln a + o(x)$ when $x\to 0$) and look for cancellations/factorizations.

Comment: canu post it as an anwers because i cannot see the code

Comment: What do you mean? I only gave you a hint (not the full-fledged solution), , and if I post as an answer it'll be "code" (Mathjax) as well.

Comment: i mean not as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to know the basic limit
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a^x-1}{x}=\log a
$$
(which you may prefer to write $\ln a$). Indeed, you have
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac {3^x + 4^x - 2^{x+1} }{x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\left(
\frac{3^x-1}{x}+
\frac{4^x-1}{x}-
2\frac{2^x-1}{x}
\right)
$$
Just rewrite the numerator as
$$
3^x+4^x-2^{x+1}=
(3^x-1)+(4^x-1)-(2\cdot2^{x}-2)=
(3^x-1)+(4^x-1)-2(2^{x}-1)
$$

Comment: i ddnt understand the  $-2 \frac {2^x - 1}{x} part

Comment: @AmmaarSolkar I added a line; basically you subtract $-1$ twice, so you have to add $2$ that goes along with $2^{x+1}=2\cdot 2^x$.

Comment: can you please solve further i tried but i cannot get the ans

Comment: @AmmaarSolkar You get $\ln3+\ln4-2\ln2=\ln3+2\ln2-2\ln2=\ln3$.

Comment: the textbook is showing $ (log_e) ^6$

Comment: @AmmaarSolkar The textbook is wrong; also the other answer has $\ln3=\log_e3$.

Comment: ok done then ty.

Answer (score 2):

*If you know and are allowed to use Taylor series:*

**Hint:** Start by rewriting $a^x = e^{x\ln a}$. Then, expand each term in the denominator to order 1 (i.e., $e^{x\ln a} = 1+x\ln a + o(x)$ when $x\to 0$) and look for cancellations/factorizations.

Details (place your mouse over the gray area to reveal it):

> $$\begin{align} 3^x+4^x - 2^{x+1} &= e^{x\ln 3}+e^{x\ln 4}+ 2\cdot 2^x = e^{x\ln 3}+e^{2x\ln 2}+ 2e^{x\ln 2} \\ &= 1+x\ln 3+1+2x\ln 2-2(1+x\ln 2) + o(x) \\ &= x\ln 3 + o(x) \end{align}$$

so that

> $$\begin{align} \frac{3^x+4^x - 2^{x+1}}{x} &= \ln 3 + o(1) \xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} \ln 3 \end{align}$$